# How to center <u> html element?

Tags: html, css

I want to make this in the center in my HTML file:

```
<a href="kobe1.html"><u style="font-size:10px">click images for more information </u></a>
```

I have tried

```css
a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="kobe1.html"><u style="font-size:10px">click images for more information </u></a>
```

```html
<center>
  <a href="kobe1.html"><u style="font-size:10px">click images for more information </u></a>
</center>
```

and

```css
a {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="kobe1.html"><u style="font-size:10px">click images for more information </u></a>
```

But nothing happen. Can anybody help me?.

Comment: Have you tried left 50% with any kind of positioning?

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: It's best to apply these kind of styles to a container like SPAN or DIV elements.   Wrapping everything inside center tag e.g. `<center><a href="kobe1.html"><u style="font-size:10px">click images for more information </u></a></center>` should also do it.

Comment: The second one actually works... perhaps not in some ultra new browsers, you couls use it too to support ie7 and lower addittionally to the solution provided in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply  use div

we can write is as

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
  /* On the container */
}
.small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <a href="kobe1.html"><u class="small">click images for more information</u></a>
</div>
```

or

```html
<div style="text-align:center">    

 <a href="kobe1.html"><u style="font-size:10px">click images for more information </u></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The other answers either show complete misunderstanding about how text aligning work in CSS, or completely fail to explain it.

In CSS, there are two major types of elements, blocks (like `<div>`, `<p>` and `<h1>`) and inlines (like `<span>`, `<a>` and `<u>`).

You cannot cast `text-align: center` on an inline, because when you think about it, it doesn't make any sense (what does it mean to center a single bolded word inside of a bunch of text?).

You *can* however, cast `text-align: center` on a **block**, which will then make all of the text **and inlines** inside that block, to be aligned to the center. Hence, the correct solution is to find the closest block parent, or create one:

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
  /* On the container */
}
.small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <a href="whatever"><u class="small">Text here!</u></a>
</div>
```